# aspclassic - Datediff treat every month with 30 days

Tags: asp-classic, datediff

How to DateDiff calculate every month from a range with exactly 30 days.

**Example:**

```
2016-03-01  2016-03-31 = 30 days
2016-04-01  2016-04-30 = 30 days
2016-05-01  2016-05-31 = 30 days
2016-06-01  2016-06-30 = 30 days
total= 120 days
```

**Using DateDiff**

```
datediff("d",cdate("2016-3-01"),cdate("2016-6-30"))    
return = 121 days
```

I need him to consider 30-day months and years with 365

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, because it is not as simple as it seems.  The corect answer, from a code efficiency point of view, depends on the code language you are using.  But, generically, consider this;

```
Sub Days_of_30()
' declare some Variables

  Dim YBeg, YEnd, Y  'Years: Start, End, Loop Yr Val
  Dim M1, M2         'Months
  Dim iDif           'Day Dif
  Dim nxtYR          'Required coz no GoTo

 //parameters here
   YBeg = 2016        'Set Start Year
   YEnd = 2019        'Set End Year

 //General Code 

  For Y = YBeg To YEnd
   nxtYR = Y + 0
     For M1 = 1 To 12  'Loop each Month

     M2 = M1 + 1

     Select Case M1
       Case 12
         nxtYR = Y + 1
         M2 = 1
     End Select

     iDif = DateDiff("d", CDate(M1 & "/" & 1 & "/" & Y), _
                          CDate(M2 & "/" & 1 & "/" & nxtYR))

     //*** Output here
     If iDif = 30 Then Debug.Print CDate(M1 & "/" & 1 & "/" & Y)
   Next
 Next

End Sub
```

This should output all 30 day months in the param range.  Obviously the code could be much more efficient (faster) with GoTo Statements but, some people don't know how to use them efficeiently, so most 'modern' languages don't use GoTo (shame, sigh).

Assuming you are using a scripting lang which does not implicitly declare var types, the above should work, but ideally, if your lang of choice supports var type declarations you should use them.

Hope You find this useful.

Gary